# Mouse gets stuck in lower edge of screen on portrait oriented window

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display

I have dual monitors running on a laptop.

- laptop monitor
- 22" monitor

the 22" is portrait oriented and when I try to move the mouse back and forth it will get stuck in the 22" unless I am high enough to pass over.

Is there a way to fix/override this behavior?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your monitors are probably logically (that is, in the computer's mind) set up like this:

```
+--------+ +---------+
|        | |         |
|        | |         |
|        | |         |
+--------+ |         |
           |         |
           |         |
           |         |
           |         |
           +---------+
```

Right-click on the desktop, and select "Screen Resolution". In the window that appears, you can drag the boxes around relative to each other. These boxes are your monitors. If you align them in there like they are on your desktop, it will be easier to move your mouse between the monitors.

For instance, my monitors are set up like this:

```
           +--------+
           |        |
+--------+ |        |
|        | |        |
|        | +--------+
|        |
+--------+
```

Comment: +1 for ASCII-art.  I was worried my text description would be hard to understand, so you sir win the prize.

Answer (score 5):

If the displays are not the same resolution, there is no way to do this.  The borders are on a pixel to pixel ratio - the best you can do is to adjust the alignment in the screen resolution settings to be the way that you want it.  There may be a third-party workaround, but I don't know of one off hand.

If the displays ARE the same resolution, this shouldn't be happening.  Of course, that's unlikely to be the case here if you have a 22" in portrait because I assume the laptop is in landscape.

Comment: Good point - I forgot about the resolution differences. I keep my monitor and laptop at different distances from me to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

Amazing. I was having this issue only on the upper left corner of my middle monitor, going left.
My original config was like this:

```
+--------+ +---------+ +-------+
|        | |         | |       |
|        | |         | |       |
|        | |         | |       |
+--------+ +---------+ +-------+
```

All I did was change it to this and it worked perfectl

```
+--------+
|        | +--------+ +--------+
|        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        |
+--------+ |        | |        |
           +--------+ +--------+
```

If the boxes don't show up correctly ... I just made the left screen the highest by a bit and the other two slightly lower.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? The diagram is highly unclear to me.

Comment: Is this a question or a me-too?

Answer (score 0):

For googlers: If you know all about display positioning mentioned in the other monitors, but notice a similar problem where the mouse cannot escape the monitor unless the velocity is high, check here:

http://winaero.com/blog/fix-mouse-pointer-sticks-on-the-edge-when-moving-between-multiple-monitors/

Comment: Thank you for you contribution, but whilst this may potentially answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential information here, and provide the link for reference. Please **edit your answer** to include that information. Thanks :)