# Windows 7 Dualview: Allow mouse transfer to smaller monitor on complete display height

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have a 2 monitor setup, a large 2560x1440 main monitor and a second 1080p monitor to the left. However, there's always a significant amount of screenheight where my mouse gets stuck when I try to switch to the smaller monitor. Is there a way in Windows 7 (through a Nvidia Driver Setting, or a thirdparty tool) to always be able to switch to the smaller monitor when I move my mouse over the left edge of my primary monitor? I'm aware that I can drag/arrange the monitor icons, but theres always a certain area where my mouse will still get stuck, either top or bottom.

[image]

/update: As stated in the comments: While repositioning to best match my physical setup does indeed help to make monitorswitching more intuitive, I would love to see a thirdparty solution to enable the switch to the smaller monitor over the complete displayheight. Thats the info the proposed duplicate thread doesnt provide. Maybe someone does know a tool for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouse gets stuck in lower edge of screen on portrait oriented window](http://superuser.com/questions/281176/mouse-gets-stuck-in-lower-edge-of-screen-on-portrait-oriented-window)

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by "your mouse icon gets stuck" I have used mutliple monitors with different resolutions in a near identical setup for years and never had this problem.

Comment: While repositioning to best match my physical setup does indeed help to make monitorswitching more intuitive, I would love to see a thirdparty solution to enable the switch to the smaller monitor over the complete displayheight. Thats the info the proposed duplicate thread doesnt provide. Maybe someone does know a tool for this?